# Can we keep an eye out for off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic

As already discussed to some extent on:

[Beware the slopes of “As an expat …”](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/beware-the-slopes-of-as-an-expat)

and

[When does travel become residency?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/when-does-travel-become-residency)

there are a few questions creeping in that are just pure travel questions.

For example, one about [getting more pages in your passport](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/151/my-us-passport-is-out-of-pages-for-visa-stamps-what-can-i-do). Yes, it's a problem that you could have as an expat, but just like depression as mentioned in the 'as an expat' example, it's not specifically down to being an expat - I could do it at home. **question has since been edited to be more expat-related**

Another one asks about [borrowing a friend's car insurance when holidaying in South Africa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/187/do-i-need-car-insurance-in-south-africa).  Nowhere in that question is the OP an expat.  It's a great question, but is surely off topic for this site, and should be on something like Travel.Stackexchange.

*(Perhaps the mods can move that one so that it still gets an answer on Travel?)*

Anyway, I'm excited by the site, but in the early days of beta we need to be super strict to make sure it stays on topic and focused.

Comment: Not saying that the holiday question should stay but aren't we precisely defining what the topic exactly is during the private beta (as opposed to enforcing some fully defined scope)?

Comment: agree that we need to err on the side of too strict rather than not strict enough.

Comment: Super-strictness does not make sure the site stays on topic. Honest questions and honest answers do.

Answer (score 6):

The "getting more pages in your passport" was a bit of a fluke, my bad. I *had* the context of needing to do it while out of the country, in the process of trying to make the question more applicable, I ended up dropping the context that I meant to put *in* the question to begin with.

That was an actual problem that I faced which ended up causing me a bunch of time consuming trips to all the wrong places in an effort to expedite other paperwork - had I known I could have simply had more pages put in my passport, I could have saved probably 40 hours of leg work.

The lesson learned here, don't drop the tiny (however self-specifics) circumstances that clearly set the difference in an effort to ask a more broadly applicable question. Had I rambled on a bit about delays in paperwork and processing and such, it wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured there was just context missing, given your role here - and I'm glad it's been sorted (I voted to reopen) :)

Comment: Yeah, I just made an edit to this question as well to add more info relevant to expats in specific. The major thing is that if you're a citizen of the country you're trying to enter, they won't deny you entry because you don't have enough space in your passport to stamp. On the other hand, if I took a trip to Korea, came back to Japan, and didn't have enough pages (despite being a resident), they could book me on a flight to the US as a result. That is definitely something to be aware of, as you can be prevented from returning to your home.