# Once again, are questions about living in country X on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

According to the rules in the [help center](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) , the question [Period of notice to quit job in Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/period-of-notice-to-quit-job-in-germany) is off topic as being an expat is not relevant in this case. The community voted [not to close](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/close/730) it  , but if we allow such questions, we should change the rules in the help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed.  I point to [this question on keeping an eye out for off topic questions](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/can-we-keep-an-eye-out-for-off-topic-questions?rq=1) and the several questions that it points to as well.

It's going to be hard to get used to initially, I suspect, but it'll evolve. We just need to remain vigilant. That question you mention is now closed.